# More than one instance of Ad in app

Tags: ios, firebase, admob

I use Firebase AdMob module to display Interstitial Ads in my App. I follow this [guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial) to create them. My App displays Ads in few places.

What is the best practice? Should I create separate `GADInterstitial` with `adUnitID` for every place where I display Ad or create one and share it between them?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would probably be to have only one GADInterstitial that you set up in your AppDelegate or using a Singleton maybe, so that you can use the same instance of your Ad throughout the whole application. That way you only need to present the Ad by accessing AppDelegate from the View Controller you want to show an Ad on, and it also avoids duplicating your code everywhere.